# User Specified Stored Procedure Name in SqlCommand

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-injection

I'm creating a `SqlCommand` with the name of the stored procedure specified by the user in `UserStoredProcedureName` using the following code:

```
new SqlCommand(UserStoredProcedureName, connection)
               { CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure }
```

There is no validation done on the string supplied by the user in `UserStoredProcedureName`. Is the user only able to specify the name of stored procedures in the database? Is the user able to perform a SQL injection attack by crafting a malicious stored procedure name?

For example:

```
UserStoredProcedureName = "SELECT * FROM USERS";
```

Comment: Have you tried it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't let external code supply a stored procedure name. Reasons: the stored procedure could be `sp_executesql`, which can run *anything that you supply as the first pararmeter*. It could also be `xp_cmdshell` or similar.

So: you should still control the input stored procedure name via a white-list. If the name is coming from your own code, it shouldn't be a problem, and it isn't normal to white-list in that scenario.

Note: if a stored procedure internally uses `EXEC (@sql)` or `EXEC sp_executesql @sql`, then it can still present a SQL injection attack, depending on whether `@sql` could contain malicious non-parameterized SQL. Note that `sp_executesql` is *designed* to allow you to fully parameterize dynamic SQL, to avoid SQL injection attacks even inside SQL generated inside SQL.

Answer (score 4):

The sql injection attack won't happen on the stored procedure itself, but it can happen on arguments/parameters that are supplied. [There's a good article that explains it a bit](https://www.jardinesoftware.net/2016/10/26/sql-injection-calling-stored-procedures-dynamically/).

For example, you could call SP_MYPROC which is fine, but I could inject on the first parameter:

```
;drop table users
```

And no, there's no "validation" per say of stored procedures other than failing if they're not found.

In general I think it's a *very bad* idea to allow someone to write in text that you then execute as a statement, especially if the login has write access. If you wanted to be safer you could build a drop down menu by querying available stored procedures, then when you go to run one you could verify a 1=1 match between what's being requested to run and the procedures names available.

But to allow free-form text on the parameter side, that's where it's going to head south quick.

I'm only familiar with specifying parameters explicitly, like:

```
sqlcommand.parameters.addwithvalue(x,y);
```

But in that case the procedure's name and parameters are hard-coded.